# Android Dagger-Hilt ignores @Provides method

Tags: android, kotlin, dependency-injection, retrofit2, dagger-hilt

I have a `NetworkModule` and a `RepositoryModule`. In my `NetworkModule` I have methods that create a retrofit service instance (there are also methods for creating the `okHttpClient` and `gson`, but those are not relevant):

```kotlin
@Module
@InstallIn(SingletonComponent::class)
object NetworkModule {

    @Singleton
    @Provides
    fun provideRetrofit(okHttpClient: OkHttpClient, gson: Gson): Retrofit {
        return Retrofit.Builder()
            .addConverterFactory(ScalarsConverterFactory.create())
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create(gson))
            .baseUrl("null")
            .client(okHttpClient)
            .build()
    }

    @Singleton
    @Provides
    fun provideApiService(retrofit: Retrofit): ApiService {
        return retrofit.create(ApiService::class.java)
    }
}
```

Then I want to use the `ApiService` in my `RepositoryModule` but Hilt just ignores that the Provides method for it in `NetworkModule` even exists. I've looked at the generated code and can't find a mention of `provideApiService`. Android Studio also marks it as unused. I'm sure the thing should work, Android Studio even shows it in the related files: [image: android studio related files]

Here is the `NetworkModule`:

```kotlin
@Module
@InstallIn(SingletonComponent::class)
object RepositoryModule {

    @Singleton
    @Provides
    fun provideLoginRepository(
        userMessage: MutableLiveData<Message>,
        apiService: ApiService
    ): LoginRepository {
        return LoginRepositoryImpl(userMessage, apiService)
    }
}
```

When I try to build it, I get this error:

```
error: [Dagger/MissingBinding] LoginRepository cannot be provided without an @Provides-annotated method.
```

At first it seemed like the repository fails to inject but I've pin pointed it to the ApiService, since if I delete it from `provideLoginRepository` method parameters, it builds successfully.

I've been trying to solve this for hours and tried pretty much everything. If anyone knows what's up with this I would be so greatful. Thanks in advance.

EDIT: Creating the instance of `ApiService` inside the `provideLoginRepository` function makes everything work and the app successfully builds, this is not the desired fix tho:

```kotlin
@Singleton
@Provides
fun provideLoginRepository(
    userMessage: MutableLiveData<Message>,
    retrofit: Retrofit
): LoginRepository {
    return LoginRepositoryImpl(userMessage, retrofit.create(ApiService::class.java))
}
```

Comment: How is `userMessage: MutableLiveData<Message>` provided? This could be the culprit and as a side effect `LoginRepository` cannot be provided.

Comment: @MarkKeen I thought about that too, but it was eliminated when I built it successfully without the ApiService. Just for completion tho, this is how it is provided:
 `@Singleton @Provides fun provideUserMessenger(): MutableLiveData<Message> { return MutableLiveData<Message>()  }` (ugly comment formatting, sorry)

Comment: what happens when you remove the arguments from the `provideLoginRepository()` fun and return an empty object i.e. `provideLoginRepository() : LoginRepository = object : LoginRepository { .... overridden methods }` - so you aren't relying on a provider chain.

Comment: . and of course I assume you have cleaned the build cache before retrying each time ..

Comment: @MarkKeen well that is almost exactly what I did, but only removed `apiService`. After that it builds successfully. To be clear, creating the service instance inside `provideLoginRepository()` works and also builds (see my edit)

Comment: ok  I see now .. hmm .. remove `@InstallIn(SingletonComponent::class)` from `NetworkModule` and add `@Module(include = [NetworkModule::class])` to `RepositoryModule` - same result?  I have never used hilt, but reading the documentation looks like more magic on top of magic .. Failing that I can't obviously see .. but ultimately will be an obvious (or annoying) solution..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I've fixed the issue. It turns out java does not (as opposed to kotlin) support `interface` in the package name. And guess what, the `ApiService` was in a package called `interface`. After renaming the package, everything works as expected.